# how to add index next to md-list-item angularsjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a string list in my html using angular md-list-item:

```
 <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in myList">
       <p>{{ item }}</p>
 </md-list-item>
```

so im getting a list of strings:

str1

str2
 ..

but now i want to add indext next to the string:

```
1. str1

2. str2
...
```

is there a simple way i can do this in angularjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `$index`

```
 <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in myList">
       <p>{{ $index}}. {{ item }}</p>
 </md-list-item>
```